# Response not ready in .then()

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise

I have a function that returns a promise that eventually returns an array.  In my .then when i try to access my first item in the array it is still undefined.  When i log the response is is correct but if i access the items inside it fails.

```
myPromise().then((response)=>{
  ///consoles array
  console.log(response);
  //undefined
  console.log(response[0]);
  //consoles the item
  setTimeout(function(){console.log(response[0])}, 1000);
}

baseCall( url ){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
     request(url , (error, response, json) => {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
          resolve(JSON.parse(json));  
             } else {
                reject("Error: Something wrong");
             }
      });
   });
}

myPromise(){
   let myReturn = [];
   baseCall( 'sampleurl' ).then((response)=>{
      response['valueNeed'].forEach(value =>{
          let addValue = {};
          addValue["someItem'] = value.someItem;
          //.... add more stuff
          myReturn.push(addValue);
      }
   }).then(()=>{
      resole(myReturn);
   });
}
```

Json Being Parsed

```
{
  "valueNeed":[
     {"id": 1, "someItem": "someVal1"},
     {"id": 2, "someItem": "someVal2"}
   ]
}
```

How do I get this to work without a timeout? I thought the .then method wasnt suppose to fire until the promise had resolved.

Comment: Are you using 'fetch' API or axios ?

Comment: @Sohail I'm using request right now.

Answer (score 0):

`response` will be the HTTP response object, not your Array. You can try `response.body`. Alternatively, like the callback approach, `body` may be passed as a second parameter i.e.

```
request().then((res, body) => { console.log(body) })
```

Comment: i should clarify.  I'm not returning the response. I'm creating an array from the response.body in the method and returning the array with all the objects returned. I'll update my question to show.

Comment: @levif1 you need to show an example of the JSON being parsed, the issue is looking more like nothing to do with `request` and everything to do with how you are indexing into it

Comment: The array that i get back in myPromise() is there when i console.log(). I just dont know why when i try to access an item in the array it says its undefined, but if i setTimeout and console log it works. @James

Comment: @levif1 there's a typo in your code, just ruling that out? i.e. `respone['valueNeed']` should be `response["valueNeed"]`.

Comment: Thanks.  That was just an example of my code.  I just typed it wrong while writing it up.

Answer (score -5):

try to assign response to another variables like `const tempvariable = response` and then use that tempvariable to access the array, sometimes react cleans up memory and weird things like that can happen.

Comment: you're not returning anything in your myPromise() method and i don't see where you're getting the resolve callback in the last then from you should return a new promise in the myPromise() method and then resolve that one with the resolve callback provided by the Promise constructor `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { baseCall('url').then(res => { ... }).then(() => resolve(myReturn))  })`